# OSCOLA Biblatex and UN Resolutions

Tags: biblatex, indexing, oscola

I'd like to cite UN resolutions using the OSCOLA Biblatex package (from Paul Stanley).
I have my entry in the .bib file as:

```
@misc{UNGA_Res2222, 
  institution  = {UNGA},
  title        = {Treaty on Principles Governing the Activities of States in the Exploration and Use of Outer Space, including the Moon and Other Celestial Bodies}, 
  instrument_no= {RES 2222 (XXI)}, 
  date         = {1966-12-19},
  entrysubtype = {undoc}}
```

and have the biblatex package engaged as so

```
\usepackage[style=oscola,
        indexing=cite,
        backend=biber,
        ecli=yes,
        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
```

but there seems to be no `virtual indexes' to have a hook for the UN Resolutions.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se

Comment: You do the hooking, basically. Documentation, p16 (do `texdoc oscola`):`tabulate` field in the bib entry, or "use the \DeclareIndexAssociation{category}{index} macro. It takes two arguments. The first is the category of entries you want included in the index, selected from the list in table 1. The second is the index you want to receive the data in relation to that category of entry".

Comment: Can you add a small (dummy) working example (not your actual full file)? It will save a huge amount of time, and also be something to test solutions against.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what programs you run to generate the indexes.

Here, I use imakeidx package (there are others) and do

```
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of Cases}]
\makeindex[name=unres, title={Table of UN Resolutions},columns=1]
```

and run

```
latex, biber, latex, latex, splitindex, latex, splitindex, latex
```

to settle the page numbers as each component is inserted.

[image: UN Res]

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{UNGA_Res2222, 
  institution  = {UNGA},
  title        = {Treaty on Principles Governing the Activities of States in the Exploration and Use of Outer Space, including the Moon and Other Celestial Bodies}, 
  instrument_no= {RES 2222 (XXI)}, 
  date         = {1966-12-19},
  entrysubtype = {undoc},
  tabulate = {unres},
  }
\end{filecontents*}  
  
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
        indexing=cite,
        backend=biber,
        ecli=yes,
        babel=hyphen,
        autocite=footnote,
        ]{biblatex}
        
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of Cases}]
\makeindex[name=unres, title={Table of UN Resolutions},columns=1]




\begin{document}
\printindexearly[unres]


text\autocite{UNGA_Res2222}

latex, biber, latex, latex, splitindex, latex, splitindex, latex

\end{document}
```

and the footnote:

[image: footnote]

---

If yours is not a legal work, do a `\printindex[unres]` at the end of the document instead.